# Grid Checkbox Select

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, telerik-grid

I made a grid with checkbox. I can only select one value at the time but I want to select more. How can I select more values at the time in a checkbox? 
**(I am using a telerik:radgrid)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code  :

> AllowMultiRowSelection="True"

```
 <telerik:RadGrid RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowMultiRowSelection="True">
        <ClientSettings>
          <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" EnableDragToSelectRows="true" />
        </ClientSettings>
      </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Comment: @ToxicPickle Please select his answer as accepted (Green check sign), It is the best way to show recognition for a good answer :)